# praw: get submission flair

Tags: reddit, praw

I'm using PRAW to work with reddit submissions, specifically submissions that have been resolved and have their "flair" attribute set to SOLVED (as described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/comments/uh88h/ability_to_mark_your_posts_as_solved_has_been/)).

However, I am getting "None" when I check for flair, even for submissions that I can see have been set to SOLVED.

I have the following code, which works with a submission that has definitely been set to SOLVED.

```
solvedSubmission = reddit.submission(url='https://www.reddit.com/r/PhotoshopRequest/comments/6ctkpj/specific_can_someone_please_remove_kids_12467_i/')
pprint.pprint(vars(solvedSubmission))
```

This outputs:

```
{'_comments_by_id': {},  
'_fetched': False,
'_flair': None,
'_info_params': {}, 
'_mod': None, 
'_reddit': <praw.reddit.Reddit object at 0x10e3ae1d0>, 
'comment_limit': 2048, 
'comment_sort': 'best', 
'id': '6ctkpj'}
```

Can anyone offer any insight as to why I'm seeing "None", on this post and other solved posts?  Is there another way that reddit keeps track of solved posts that I should look into?

Thank you!

Comment: You're sure the reddit instance is valid?

Comment: It should be.  I'm calling it using my client_id, client_secret, user_agent, username, and password.  However, I don't think I'm "fetching" the data correctly.  When I try getting the subreddit with additional parameter "fetch=True", I get errors such as "Reddit object has no attribute 'get_subreddit'", or "__call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fetch'" https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/v3.6.0/pages/code_overview.html#praw.objects.Subreddit

Answer (score 5):

By now (~1y after OP) you might have solved this already, but it came up in a search I did, and since I figured out the answer, I will share.

The reason you never saw any relevant information is because [PRAW uses lazy objects so that network requests to Reddit’s API are only issued when information is needed](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html#determine-available-attributes-of-an-object). You need to make it non-lazy in order to retrieve all of the available data. Below is a minimal working example:

```
import praw
import pprint

reddit = praw.Reddit() # potentially needs configuring, see docs
solved_url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/PhotoshopRequest/comments/6ctkpj/specific_can_someone_please_remove_kids_12467_i/'

post = reddit.submission(url=solved_url)
print(post.title) # this will fetch the lazy submission-object...
pprint.pprint(vars(solvedSubmission)) # ... allowing you to list all available fields
```

In the `pprint`-output, you will discover, as of the time of writing this answer (Mar 2018), the following field:

```
...
'link_flair_text': 'SOLVED',
...
```

... which is what you will want to use in your code, e.g. like this:

```
is_solved = 'solved' == post.link_flair_text.strip().lower()
```

So, to wrap this up, you need to make PRAW issue a network request to fetch the submission object, to turn it from a lazy into a full instance; you can do this either by printing, assigning to a variable, or by going the direct route into the object by using the field-name you want.